# Render selected image from flux:field.file

Tags: typo3, fluid

How can I render the image selected by the `flux:field.file` ViewHelper?

This is my configuration:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
      <flux:form id="tabslide">
         <flux:form.option.group value="myvalue" />
         <flux:form.section name="slideItems">
            <flux:form.object name="slideItem">
               <flux:field.input name="myinput" label="My Input" />
               <flux:field.file name="myfile" label="Bild" allowed="jpg,png,svg,gif" showThumbnails="1" useFalRelation="TRUE" minItems="0" maxItems="1" />
            </flux:form.object>
         </flux:form.section>
      </flux:form>
</f:section>
```

I already tried:

```
<f:for each="{slideItems}" as="element" key="id">
    <f:image src="{element.myfile}"/>
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me now. Apparently I forgot the `slideItem`.

```
<f:for each="{slideItems}" as="element" key="id">
    <f:image src="{element.slideItem.myfile}"/>
</f:for>
```